# Track Log In Attempts Without Using Database - ASP Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, iis, ip

I am working on a web application, asp net web forms site (.Net 4.0, C#).

I want to be able to ban a user's IP either temporarily or permanently.

A permanent ban would occur if the IP address is attempting to log in using multiple usernames and passwords. This would signify a malicious attacker, so I want to ban them. I would like to avoid using the database at this step to avoid DOS type attacks slowing down the network.

A temporary IP ban would occur if the user types in the wrong username, such as `username1` instead of `username`, and they keep trying to log in with their password. This method will use the database as the user might have not realizes they typed in the wrong username.

My question is:

How can I track if the same or different user name has been used across the page refreshes?

I am thinking about using a Session, but after some searching around for similar problems, it looks like  the Session requires cookies and an attacker would avoid those.

For permanent IP bans, I found some code that uses the IIS api and the Microsoft.Web.Administration package. Here is the link for some code adding IPs to the IIS ban list:

[IIS IP Security](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/ipsecurity/add)

How can I implement the tracking of the log in attempts without using the database?

I am also implementing the server (IIS) IP restrictions as another layer of security, but this only blocks an IP based on the number of attempts within a certain time period (which is desired) but does not differentiate between the cases I mentioned above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using any client side storage such as sessions or cookies seems like a bad way to deter an attacker.  You say that you don't want to use the database because it could slow down the network so my suggestion would be to use a second local database or a in memory list to hold information pertaining to recent login attempts.  It could store IP address, username, hashed password, and a time stamp.  When you go to authenticate a user you could check against this local data.  [MSND Article on caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478965.aspx) for more information.

Comment: I have started looking into caching and I think it will do what I need to. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are using html 5.0, you could use the local storage ability. Of course, malicious users may have disabled that, as well as cookies, but worth considering.

Comment: Unfortunately, this application is a little older and does not use HTML 5.